# Simple HTML Dom get href that begins with

Tags: simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom to extract information from a remote source. I would like to get all href links that contain a particular piece of text (not all on a page). I have tried

```
->find('a[href*="/place"]')
```

and

```
->find('a[href="/place"*]')
```

and

```
->find('a[href="/place*"]')
```

but this returns empty results.

The href I am trying to get must begin with the text "/place".

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match elements that have the specified attribute and it starts with a certain value, use `[attribute^=value]`.

```
->find('a[href^="/place"]')
```

Ref: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_find_attr

Comment: Great thanks. This worked. I did try that however I put the ^ after the =. My bad, so sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I do not now this app, however did you try using the asterisk like so ?

```
>find('a[href="/place*"]')
```

Comment: Sorry yes I did. I should have added that in to the question.